# Как кодировать категориальные признаки, содержащие Nan, без добавления новой категории?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Например, признак, который принимает значения `{'Male', 'Female', NaN}`, при использовании `OneHotEncoder` (или какого-нибудь другого средства) переводил этот признак в два численных и кодировал:

```
         f1      f2  
Male      1       0
Female    0       1
Nan       0       0
```

Другой пример:
Исходный датасет:

```
           Gender        City
Person1      Male      Moscow
Person2       Nan       Kazan
Person3    Female     Saratov
```

Полученный датасет:

```
            f1(Male)   f2(Female)   f3(Moscow)   f4(Saratov)   f5(Kazan)
Person1            1            0            1             0           0
Person2            0            0            0             1           0
Person3            0            1            0             0           1
```

При этом, такой датасет должен получаться вне зависимости от того, имел ли сет, на котором тренировался энкодер, `Nan` в каких-то категориях.

Comment: а как вы дальше планируете работать с этой транспонированной матрицей?? И как вы планируете объединить разные признаки в таком закодированном виде в одну матрицу?

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе маленький входной датасет с 3-5 строк и с 2+ признаками (причем так, чтобы у разных признаков было разное количество уникальных значений ) и привести то, что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: @MaxU смысл в том, что если на вход encoder.transform() передается признак, который содержит Nan, хотя encoder.fit() не содержал такого случая, то ошибки не должно возникать

Comment: Попробуйте привести в вопросе входной и выходной датасеты (как я описал во втором комментарии) - тогда поймете, что я имею ввиду)

Comment: Для борьбы с `NaN` существуют "Imputers" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне нужно, чтобы Nan не считался отдельным значением признака, а
>   считался отсутствием какого-либо значения

Проще всего будет просто удалить столбцы относящиеся к `NaN` значениям.

Пример:

Пусть у нас следующий фрейм:

```
In [39]: df
Out[39]:
         Gender     City
Person1    Male   Moscow
Person2     NaN    Kazan
Person3  Female  Saratov
```

Решение:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')

df_encoded = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
    enc.fit_transform(df.fillna('N/A')),
    columns=enc.get_feature_names()
)
```

получился следующий DataFrame:

```
In [41]: df_encoded
Out[41]:
   x0_Female  x0_Male  x0_N/A  x1_Kazan  x1_Moscow  x1_Saratov
0        0.0      1.0     0.0       0.0        1.0         0.0
1        0.0      0.0     1.0       1.0        0.0         0.0
2        1.0      0.0     0.0       0.0        0.0         1.0
```

теперь нам нужно избавиться от всех столбцов, которые оканчиваются на `"_N/A"`:

```
In [48]: mask = df_encoded.columns.str.contains(r"_N/A$")

In [49]: df_encoded = df_encoded.loc[:, ~mask]
```

Результат:

```
In [50]: df_encoded
Out[50]:
   x0_Female  x0_Male  x1_Kazan  x1_Moscow  x1_Saratov
0        0.0      1.0       0.0        1.0         0.0
1        0.0      0.0       1.0        0.0         0.0
2        1.0      0.0       0.0        0.0         1.0
```

---

Также можно воспользоваться параметрами `categories=[<list_of_categories>]` и `handle_unknown='ignore'` в [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), но это более трудоемкий путь, т.к. придется кодировать каждый столбец отдельно, задавая список уникальных значений в качестве `categories`.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно закодировать значения признака таким образом, чтобы при появлении новых значений не появлялись новые столбцы, то можно воспользоваться [Hashing Encoding](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/hashing.html), также известным как [Hashing Trick](https://booking.ai/dont-be-tricked-by-the-hashing-trick-192a6aae3087) - в этом случае вы заранее указываете максимальное число столбцов в выходном (после кодирования) датасете.

PS [Краткое пояснение алгоритма "hashing trick"](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-explain-feature-hashing-in-an-easily-understandable-way)

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы Nan не считался отдельным значением признака, а считался отсутствием какого-либо значения